# Scrapy+Tkinter -> exe cx freeze ( scrapy function doesn't work after compiling to exe )

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrapy, cx-freeze

The problem is that I can not run Scrapy function inside my tkinter gui, when it's compiled to .exe

Everything works great, when I just run not compiled .py file

my setup file:

```
print('don"t look at this string, SO said it should be here')
https://pastebin.com/0ERecUaA
```

guess you do not need other 2 work .py files, because they work perfectly when I run them from console

BTW: I get no errors while processing compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding

```
"idna", "email.mime.multipart", "email.mime.text","email.mime"
```

to packages